# implement a router based on available thread to process

Tags: multithreading, spring-integration, priority-queue

I am trying to see if I can implement this using spring integration before I write custom code for same.

I have N channels, each channel need to be processed by X threads. These are to process requests that takes long to process, 2-20 minutes.

Now upstream, I will have a router that will route an incoming request to one of these N channels only if not all threads (for that channel) are busy, it can adopt a round robin strategy to find a channel with a free thread. If it cannot find a free channel (assume all channels are busy) just put it back in input channel (so it can be retried in next polling cycle).

So my key questions at the moment are,  how can I inject channels in a router and then how to know if  all threads processing a channel X are busy?

Any relevant code sample will be greatly helpful.
if there is an alternate approach to achieve same result, please point in that direction.

Thank You

Comment: I don't quite understand. What's wrong with a simple producer-consumer pattern in which you have a thread pool which polls from a queue?

Comment: Perhaps you should describe your use case; this seems a little over-complicated.

Comment: Application is not that simple, although that would be the basis if i will have to code it myself. I am trying to see if SI can help me somehow to reduce the burden, i really like the clean way of building app using SI with minimum code with SI taking care of all expansive thread management. Just to give you some more on the topic, incoming requests need to pre processed  and evaluated, some may be dropped, in some cases they should only go to channel A for example not to channel B or C.

Comment: ..Also the the process should support priority based processing, all these things are very easy to implement as POJO and wire together using SI, than write a monolithic multi-threaded large application.

Comment: Gary, although there several trivial things that need to be implemented but at the heart of it, I have 3 servers that process request, but they limit max number of concurrent connections to 10 each. So I need to build a SI workflow (as entry point) that knows which server to use for a incoming request and maximizes the use of all 3 servers with each being used about the same. If we have more requests, they need to queue up (in priority queue) until one of the server is available.